# Global scope variable is null within Scriptblock

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Running the following code produces an error because the variable used for path is resolved as null event though it defined in the script:

```
$ServerName = "test01"
$RemotePath = "C:\Test\"
$TestScriptBlock = { copy-item -Path $RemotePath  -Destination C:\backup\ -Force -Recurse } 
$CurrentSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName

Invoke-Command -Session $CurrentSession -ScriptBlock $TestScriptBlock
```

How do I call the $RemotePath defined in the parent script from within the ScriptBlock? I need to use $RemotePath in other parts of the parent script. Note, this value doesn't change, so it can be a constant.

**UPDATE -- WORKING SOLUTION**

You have to pass in variable as parameter to the scriptblock:

```
$ServerName = "test01"
$RemotePath = "C:\Test\"
$TestScriptBlock = { param($RemotePath) copy-item -Path $RemotePath  -Destination C:\backup\ -Force -Recurse } 
$CurrentSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName

Invoke-Command -Session $CurrentSession -ScriptBlock $TestScriptBlock -ArgumentList $RemotePath
```

Comment: use can try using $global:RemotePath = "C:\Test\" as global variable which can be accessed anywhere in entire script file

Comment: tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: Does `$using:RemotePath` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two scripts there, not one. The $TestScriptBlock is a separate script nested inside the main one, you send it to the remote computer, and that remote computer doesn't have $RemotePath configured. Try:

```
$ServerName = "test01"

$TestScriptBlock = {
    $RemotePath = "C:\Test\"
    copy-item -Path $RemotePath  -Destination C:\backup\ -Force -Recurse 
}

$CurrentSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName

Invoke-Command -Session $CurrentSession -ScriptBlock $TestScriptBlock
```

(I would probably call it $LocalPath then, though)

Comment: Anyway of having a defining one global variable within this parent script so that I can use it in both the scriptblock and the parent script? Otherwise I'll need to have duplicate variables to maintain in the script because I need to use it in other locations outside of the script block. Note, this value doesn't change, so it can be a constant.

Comment: Yes maybe although I haven't tried - http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2012/10/26/executing-code-locally-and-remotely-using-local-variables.aspx seems like it would help.

Comment: I got it to work thanks to your link in your comment. I'll add an update above so that others can see the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this syntax:

```
$globalvariable1 = "testoutput01"
$globalvariable2 = "testoutput02"

$Scriptblock = {
    Write-Host $using:globalvariable1
    Write-Host $using:globalvariable2
}

$serverName = Domain\HostNameofServer

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $globalvariable1, $globalvariable2
```

Answer (score 0):

The execution happens in a different session and all the variables in the current scope are not copied to the remote session by default.
You can use either parameters or "using:" as explained here:

[How can I pass a local variable to a script block executed on a remote machine with Invoke-Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492437/how-can-i-pass-a-local-variable-to-a-script-block-executed-on-a-remote-machine-w)