# How do I pass a local variable to a remote `Invoke-Command`?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to retrieve the hash of a file located on remote server using `Invoke-Command`.  It works fine when I give the full path as below:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName winserver -ScriptBlock { 
    Get-FileHash -Path E:\test\testfile.zip -Algorithm SHA1 
}
```

But I need to pass the file name via a variable as below:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName winserver -ScriptBlock { 
    Get-FileHash -Path "E:\test\$dest.zip" -Algorithm SHA1 
}
```

How do I access this variable in the `scriptblock` of a remote session?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In PowerShell 4 (3+ actually) the easiest way is to use the [`Using` scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6#example-5-using-a-local-variable-in-a-remote-command):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName winserver -ScriptBlock { 
    Get-FileHash E:\test\$Using:dest.zip -Algorithm SHA1 
}
```

For a solution that works with all versions:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName winserver -ScriptBlock {
    param($myDest)

    Get-FileHash E:\test\$myDest.zip -Algorithm SHA1 
} -ArgumentList $dest
```

Answer (score 11):

To *complement* [briantist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist):

The script block passed to `Invoke-Command` is (as intended) executed on the *remote* machine, using the *remote* machine's variables by default.

Thus, **in order to use a *local* variable's value,<sup>[1]</sup> extra steps are needed** (to put it differently: inside a script block executed remotely, you cannot just refer to local variables as you normally would, such as with `$dest`):

- PS **v3+** offers the [**`using:` scope modifier**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-local-variables) for **direct use of a local variable's value inside the script block** - see briantist's first command.

  - Note that `using:` only works when `Invoke-Command` actually targets a *remote* machine, such as with the `-ComputerName` parameter.
- The only option that also works in earlier versions is to **pass the local variable as a *parameter* to the script block.** - see briantist's second command.

As an aside:

- Because the local variable values undergo *serialization*, due to the remote script block by definition running *out of process*, type fidelity is limited, though .NET primitive types and strings are *not* affected - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67808632/45375) for details.

---

<sup>[1] Note that you fundamentally cannot pass a variable *itself*, only *its value*; that is, you cannot *assign to* a local variable in a remote script block.</sup>