# Powershell not calling variables

Tags: powershell

I have this script to test a specific site. It works but not the way I want to. After the "try" parameter, the variable `$hostpc` is not getting called.

This is the output I'm getting:

> Testing Server:
>   Web Ping on  Succeeded.

It should be something like this:

> Testing Server: **servername**
>   Web Ping on **servername** Succeeded.

---

### Script

```
$servers = Get-Content 'some.txt'

Foreach ($hostpc in $servers) {

    Invoke-Command $hostpc -ScriptBlock { 

        try {

            write-host "Testing Server: $hostpc"
            $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("some web site")
            $response = $request.GetResponse()
            Write-Host "Web Ping on $hostpc Succeeded."   -foregroundcolor Yellow
        } catch {
            Write-Host ("Web Ping on $hostpc FAILED!!! The error was '{0}'." -f $_)-foregroundcolor Red
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i pass a string/variable for get-filehash inside invoke-command in powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492437/how-can-i-pass-a-string-variable-for-get-filehash-inside-invoke-command-in-power)

Comment: The short of it: local variables aren't available on remote machines by default; in PSv3+, use `$using:hostpc`; in lower versions use `-ArgumentList` and `$args[0]` or an explicit `param($hostpc)` declaration inside the script block.

Comment: UPDATEI ended up using $using:hostpc it works perfect.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Comment: @RamosT: Glad to hear it. Just to clarify: the problem was related to `Invoke-Command` (alias `icm`) executing on a _remote_ machine that doesn't have access to _local_ variables, and not related to the `try` block.

Comment: @nikhilvartak: I didn't down-vote, but I suspect it was down-voted for poor initial formatting.

Comment: I've retitled the linked question that this one's a duplicate of to make that more obvious: [How can I pass a local variable to a script block executed on a remote machine with Invoke-Command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492437/how-can-i-pass-a-local-variable-to-a-script-block-executed-on-a-remote-machine-w)

Answer (score -1):

I think your Variable and thus Ping is really working. The problem is with log display because you are not concatenating variables with string properly.

> write-host "Testing Server: $hostpc"

Change to `write-host "Testing Server: $($hostpc)"`

> Write-Host "Web Ping on $hostpc Succeeded."

Change to `Write-Host "Web Ping on $($hostpc) Succeeded."`

Comment: No, a simple variable reference such as `$hostpc` inside a double-quoted string works just fine (try `"Honey, I'm $HOME"`); see my comments on the question for what the real problem is.