# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' it is null and cannot find path

Tags: powershell

Trying to get these two to work but keep getting errors. Basically looking to pickup all files from C:\Temp\Test with .txt extension and copy it to Server1 and Server2 D:\Temp\Test.

Doesn't work...

```
$servers = "Server1","Server2"
$SourcePath = (Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\Test *.txt).Name
$servers | ForEach {
Invoke-Command $servers -ScriptBlock {
$CompName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
$DestPath = "\\$CompName\D$\Temp\Test"
Copy-Item $SourcePath -Destination $DestPath -Recurse
}
}
```

Comment: Hint: check output from `$servers | ForEach { "a server = $_"; $servers }`. Moreover, if your script throws an exception, please [edit] your script to include the exception, with both the message and the stack trace. "*Doesn't work...*" enunciation does not suffice!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a local variable to a script block executed on a remote machine with Invoke-Command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492437/how-can-i-pass-a-local-variable-to-a-script-block-executed-on-a-remote-machine-w)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common mistake actually. When you use `Invoke-Command` to invoke your scriptblock on the remote server it creates a new instance of PowerShell on that remote computer. That new instance of PowerShell has no idea what the `$SourcePath` variable is, since it was never set in that new instance. To work around this give your scriptblock a parameter, and then supply the value of `$SourcePath` when you invoke to scriptblock. It can be done like this:

```
$servers = "Server1","Server2"
$SourcePath = (Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\Test *.txt).Name
$servers | ForEach {
    Invoke-Command $servers -ScriptBlock {
        Param($SourcePath)
        $CompName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
        $DestPath = "\\$CompName\D$\Temp\Test"
        Copy-Item $SourcePath -Destination $DestPath -Recurse
    } -ArgumentList $SourcePath
}
```