# Powershell different Credentials with encapsulated arguments

Tags: powershell, credentials, invoke-command, start-process

after trying several possibilities I'am not sure how to continue.

I need to execute a script `"C:\test1\script.ps1"`  And I need to pass some Arguments with this script too. These Arguments (`-Hashtag $Hashtag -Name $Name` and so on...) are stored in a Variable called `$arguments`.

So the final call should look like : `C:\test1\script.ps1 $arguments`

That is no problem, but now the thing I can't get managed to work.

My goal is to execute this as a different user. The Login credentials are stored in `$cred`

I already tried the following things compared to related topics here in the forums:

1. Command

   ```
   Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -Authentication Credssp -ComputerName home -ScriptBlock {C:\test1\script.ps1 $arguments}
   ```

   Powershell Result: Some of the arguments (in this case the Hashtag) is empty. Im not sure why this happens cause I just filled the $arguments Variable with all the stuff.
2. Command

   ```
   Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\test1\script.ps1 $arguments -Credential $cred -WorkingDirectory 'C:\\Windows\System32'
   ```

   This results that the Script won't get executed.

Does anyone have some more info about handling that construction? Maybe there is another Command I can pass credentials to?

As another notice, I cant use Credential Prompts so any solutions where UAC get into consideration is not suitable for my problem.

Comment: `$arguments` would need to be [splatted](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx) eg. `@arguments`

Comment: I Followed the Instructions, but It won't work either.

`$arguments= @{

Argument1 = $Argument1
Argument2 = $Argument2

 }`

Comment: I Followed the Instructions, but It won't work either.

`$arguments= @{

Argument1 = $Argument1
Argument2 = $Argument2

 }`

The desired Script gets executed, thats fine. But throwing me an Error that the Arguments are empty... When I print the @arguments there are all the Data iI need. So the splatting should work proberly. But indeed these arguments son#t get passed to the script correctly. 

I call the script now like this:

`-ScriptBlock {C:\test1\script.ps1 @ausfuehrung} `

Is that correct?

Comment: If you pass it in like that, without a param block or utilizing argumentlist, then you would need to use the `using:` scope. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492437/how-can-i-pass-a-local-variable-to-a-script-block-executed-on-a-remote-machine-w)

Comment: Thanks for the advises, but I got it running with:

`start powershell.exe -Argumentlist "C:\test1\script.ps1 $arguments" -credential $credential `

Now just the return value is missing. But I am trying to solve this on my own. Thanks for the help at all :)

I learned much about splatting, which I never heard of before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -Authentication Credssp -ComputerName home -ScriptBlock {C:\test1\script.ps1} -ArgumentList 'argument1','argument2','argument3'
```

Make sure in the script, you define positional parameters. This way argument 1 is assigned to your first parameter in the script and so on.

Comment: Well, If I use this Syntax, Powershell telling me that there is no Parameter for the ParameterName "Arguments".

I wrote it like this, because the arguments change dynamicly I need to use the Variables:

 `-ScriptBlock {C:\test1\script.ps1} -Arguments $Argument1, $Argument2... `

Comment: My mistake, the parameter should be -ArgumentList

Comment: Thanks for the advises, but I got it running with:

`start powershell.exe -Argumentlist "C:\test1\script.ps1 $arguments" -credential $credential `

Now just the return value is missing. But I am trying to solve this on my own. Thanks for the help at all :)