# -ExpandProperty doesn't show all the properties via Remote PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

When I run the following code in Exchange PowerShell on an Exchange server it shows all the properties:

```
PS> Get-Mailbox Testeria | select -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses

SmtpAddress        : Tester_IA@contoso.com
AddressString      : Tester_IA@contoso.com
ProxyAddressString : smtp:Tester_IA@contoso.com
Prefix             : SMTP
IsPrimaryAddress   : False
PrefixString       : smtp

SmtpAddress        : TesterIA@contoso.com
AddressString      : TesterIA@contoso.com
ProxyAddressString : SMTP:TesterIA@contoso.com
Prefix             : SMTP
IsPrimaryAddress   : True
PrefixString       : SMTP

SmtpAddress        : TesterIA@outlook.contoso.com
AddressString      : TesterIA@outlook.contoso.com
ProxyAddressString : smtp:TesterIA@outlook.contoso.com
Prefix             : SMTP
IsPrimaryAddress   : False
PrefixString       : smtp
```

But when I try to use Remote PowerShell on the local machine via

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri ("http://" + $Server + "/PowerShell/") -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession $Session
```

and run the same code it show only this:

```
PS> Get-Mailbox Testeria | select -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses

smtp:Tester_IA@contoso.com
SMTP:TesterIA@contoso.com
smtp:TesterIA@outlook.contoso.com
```

How to understand this behaviour? How to get all the properties via Remote PowerShell?

PSVersion on the local machine is 5.1.14409.1005

PSVersion on the Exchange Server is 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably occurs because when you access objects via PSRemoting the results are deserialized. You can see this is the case by looking at the TypeName of the resulting object by pipling it to `Get-Member`. You will see Deserialized prefixed to the Type:

> Objects that have the "Deserialized." prefix in their type names are property bags that contain a deserialized representation of public
>   properties of the corresponding remote, live objects. As you can see
>   in the output of Get-Member those property bags don’t expose any
>   methods except ToString(), because usually methods cannot be invoked
>   in the remote session (for example, System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill()
>   can’t act on a remote process). Similarly setting and getting property
>   values of the property bags doesn’t execute any code (for example
>   WorkingSet property of
>   Deserialized.System.Diagnostics.Process.WorkingSet is only a snapshot
>   and doesn’t get updated when the remote process uses more memory).

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2010/01/07/how-objects-are-sent-to-and-from-remote-sessions/

My assumption is that the `EmailAddresses` property is a Script Property, which means it executes a script when called to get its sub properties. When you retrieve the object via Remoting you lose the ability to execute this script.

Unfortunately I don't have an Exchange system to verify this on at the moment.

Comment: Good pointers, but I think the real reason the `EmailAddresses` objects turn to strings is the implicit recursion-depth limit that the remoting infrastructure applies to non-well-known (scalar) objects, which replaces property values that aren't themselves instance of well-known types with their `.ToString()` values.

Answer (score 1):

[Mark Wragg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825068/45375) provides helpful pointers, but let me elaborate:

- Objects transmitted via **PowerShell's [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote) infrastructure** undergo **XML-based serialization** at the remote source, and *deserialization* on receipt by the caller.
- **With the exception of a select few *well-known* types, *type fidelity is lost* during serialization / deserialization**, and the **deserialized objects are *emulations* of the original objects**, as indicated by the `Deserialized.` prefix in their type name (as you can see by accessing `.pstypenames[0]` on a deserialized instance of by piping it to [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member)); specifically, the limitation of these emulations - beyond not having the same *type identity* as the originals - are:

  - Deserialized objects **lack the *methods*** of the original.
  - For *nested* (scalar) objects (objects composed of multiple properties whose values too are objects composed of multiple properties, ...), the object graph is limited to a depth of `1`.

    - In practice, this means that **instances of non-well-known (scalar) types serialize such that property values that aren't themselves instances of well-known types are *replaced by their `.ToString()` representations***.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for a more **comprehensive overview of serialization** as part of PowerShell's remoting infrastructure.

---

**Applied to your case**:

Via remoting, the collection of rich email-object instances originally contained in the `.EmailAddresses` property of the objects returned by the [`Get-MailBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailbox) cmdlet is converted to a collection of *strings*, by calling `.ToString()` on each email-object instance, which seemingly returns the `.ProxyAddressString` property value.

---

**Example**:

For simplicity, the following demonstrates the recursion-depth (stringification) problem via a local background job created with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) call (background jobs also use PowerShell's remoting infrastructure):

```
PS> Start-Job { 
      # Define a custom class, which is by definition not a well-known type.
      # Give it a property of another non-well-known type, [regex].
      class Foo { $Bar = [regex] 'hi' }
      # Output an instance of the custom class.
      [Foo]::new() 
    } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemove | 
        ForEach-Object {
          $_.Bar                     # Output the .Bar property value...
          $_.Bar.GetType().FullName  # ... and its data type.
        }

hi
System.String
```

As you can see, the `[regex]` instance stored in property `.Bar` was replaced by its `.ToString()` representation.