# Remote PowerShell -ExpandProperty doesn't load nested properties

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm attempting to get Exchange mailbox permissions of specific mailbox in C# using Remote PowerShell.
I need to get `SecurityIdentifier` of privileged user, as the property `User` is a nested property, im trying to load it by using  `-ExpandProperty`  PowerShell feature.

```
var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.Runspace = runspace;
var command = new Command("Get-MailboxPermission");
command.Parameters.Add("Identity", "user-smtp@test-domain.com");

powerShell.Commands.AddCommand(command);

var selectCommand = new Command("Select-Object");
selectCommand.Parameters.Add("Property", new[] {"AccessRights", "User"});
selectCommand.Parameters.Add("ExpandProperty", "User");
                
powerShell.Commands.AddCommand(selectCommand);

var result = powerShell.Invoke();

foreach (var psObject in result){
   var accessRights = psObject.Properties["AccessRights"].Value.ToString();  
   var user = psObject.Properties["User"].Value.ToString();
   var userSecurityIdentifier = psObject.Properties["SecurityIdentifier"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't return `SecurityIdentifier`.

I guess that the nested property `User` is already deserialized as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825068/8125728

Executing command as a script was working fine until [April 2021 Exchange Server Security Update](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/released-april-2021-exchange-server-security-updates/ba-p/2254617) which changed the Exchange Management Console endpoint language mode from **FullLanguage** mode to **NoLanguage** mode. **NoLanguage** mode unfortunately does not support **AddScript()**.

```
var script = "Get-MailboxPermission -Identity 'user-smtp@test-domain.com' | Select-Object -Property AccessRights, User -ExpandProperty User";
powerShell.AddScript(script);
powerShell.Invoke();
```

I know that this can done by importing session and executing script in ScriptBlock but importing the PsSession leads to huge memory usage and also to memory leak as it caches the imported modules.

```
var script = "Get-MailboxPermission -Identity 'user-smtp@test-domain.com' | Select-Object -Property AccessRights, User -ExpandProperty User";
Command command = new Command("Invoke-Command");
command.Parameters.Add("Session", session);
command.Parameters.Add("ScriptBlock", ScriptBlock.Create(script));
```

Is there any workaround how to get `SecurityIdentifier` from nested `User` property **without importing PsSession**?

Comment: It's one or the other, you can't call on a property , then try to expand another.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Sure you do - using `-Property` in conjunction with `-ExpandProperty` to flatten the object hierarchy is absolutely fine and supported. The problem here is likely that OP needs `psObject.Properties["User"].Properties["SecurityIdentifier"]` instead of `psObject.Properties["SecurityIdentifier"]`

Comment: Ohh, fancy. Good to know

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen `psObject.Properties["User"]` is already deserialized so its type is `String`

Comment: So `@{ n='SID' ; e={ $_.User.SecurityIdentifier }}` is not an option right?

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but as an aside: if you combine `-Property` with `-ExpandProperty`, the `-Property` properties are added as _NoteProperty_ members   to whatever (enumerated) instances `-ExpandProperty` returns. Therefore, use of `User` _twice_ is pointless; what `-ExpandProperty User` outputs _are_ already the (enumerated) `.User` property values.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I just tried that to be sure but unfortunately it didn't help.