# Serialization differences between PowerShell's Format-List and ConvertTo-Json

Tags: json, powershell, serialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to parse the results of PowerShell's `Get-NetIPConfiguration` in Python.

The results contain the values I want in the default formatting (Format-List), but not when converted to JSON, which is the format I would like to consume.

Note how `DNSServer` is serialized by `Format-List`:

```
PS C:\Users\BoppreH> Get-NetIPConfiguration | Format-List
InterfaceAlias       : VirtualBox Host-Only Network
InterfaceIndex       : 23
InterfaceDescription : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
IPv4Address          : 192.168.56.1
IPv6DefaultGateway   :
IPv4DefaultGateway   :
DNSServer            : fec0:0:0:ffff::1
                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2
                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3

[...]
```

while `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1` serializes the DNSServer attribute differently (in a completely useless way):

```
PS C:\Users\BoppreH> Get-NetIPConfiguration | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1
[
    {
        "Detailed":  false,
        "ComputerName":  "BOPPREH-DESKTOP",
        "InterfaceAlias":  "VirtualBox Host-Only Network",
        "InterfaceIndex":  23,
        "InterfaceDescription":  "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter",
        "CompartmentId":  1,
        "NetAdapter":  "MSFT_NetAdapter (CreationClassName = \"MSFT_NetAdapter\", DeviceID = \"{EAF79493-7C78-44D2-ADB4-F3EF196D2F49}\", SystemCreationClassName = \"CIM_NetworkPort\", SystemName = \"boppreh-desktop\")",
        "NetCompartment":  "MSFT_NetCompartment (InstanceID = \";55;\")",
        "NetIPv6Interface":  "MSFT_NetIPInterface (Name = \"??55??55;\", CreationClassName = \"\", SystemCreationClassName = \"\", SystemName = \"\")",
        "NetIPv4Interface":  "MSFT_NetIPInterface (Name = \"??55?55;\", CreationClassName = \"\", SystemCreationClassName = \"\", SystemName = \"\")",
        "NetProfile":  null,
        "AllIPAddresses":  "192.168.56.1 fe80::d83f:9609:86ff:2b57%23",
        "IPv6Address":  "",
        "IPv6TemporaryAddress":  "",
        "IPv6LinkLocalAddress":  "fe80::d83f:9609:86ff:2b57%23",
        "IPv4Address":  "192.168.56.1",
        "IPv6DefaultGateway":  null,
        "IPv4DefaultGateway":  null,
        "DNSServer":  "MSFT_DNSClientServerAddress (Name = \"23\", CreationClassName = \"\", SystemCreationClassName = \"\", SystemName = \"23\") MSFT_DNSClientServerAddress (Name = \"23\", CreationClassName = \"\", SystemCreationClassName = \"\", SystemName = \"2\")"
    },
[...]
```

It's not until depth level 4 that the addresses become visible, but by then the output is several times larger and much harder to navigate.

My current alternative is to pipe the results in `Select-Object` and use calculated properties to convert the values myself (in the case of DNSServer it's `$_.DNSServer.ServerAddresses -join " "`), but this is cumbersome to do for each property and makes other properties serialize differently too.

How can I force the JSON serializer to format values like the list formatter?

Comment: This serialization problem, coupled with a 2.5 second delay when invoking PowerShell from Python, and lack of network mask information, made me switch to manually and shamefully parsing `ipconfig /all`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note how `DNSServer` is serialized by `Format-List`

The `Format-*` cmdlets do not *serialize*, they produce *for-display string representations*, using PowerShell's [output-formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview) (as opposed to its [serialization infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67808632/45375)).

These representations are *not* meant to be used for *programmatic processing*, but if you do want to process them as *strings*, you can pipe them to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string):

```sh
# Returns a single-line string; add -Stream to get an array of lines.
# Add -Width to explicitly specify a line width (console window width is the default).
# Note: Since Format-List is used for formatting *by default*, 
#       you don't strictly need the Format-List here.
#       Alternatively, use Format-Table for a *table* representation
$stringRep = Get-NetIPConfiguration | Format-List | Out-String
```

---

> How can I force the JSON serializer to format values like the list formatter?

Your only option is indeed to simplify the object graph by constructing your own `[pscustomobject]` instances, such as via [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) and calculated properties, or in a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) loop with `[pscustomobject]` *literals* (e.g.
`[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 'bar'; baz = 'quux' }`).

For instance:

```sh
Get-NetIPConfiguration | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    InterfaceAlias = $_.InterfaceAlias
    InterfaceIndex = $_.InterfaceIndex
    InterfaceDescription = $_.InterfaceDescription
    'NetProfile.Name' = $_.NetProfile.Name
    IPv4Address = $_.IPv4Address -join "`n"
    IPv6DefaultGateway = $_.IPv6DefaultGateway.NextHop
    IPv4DefaultGateway = $_.IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop
  }
}
```

Piping the above to [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) gives a reasonable representation.

Do note that `Get-NetIPConfiguration`'s [formatting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml) has additional logic built in that varies the output fields in its for-display representations *by adapter type*, which the above doesn't take into account.

Comment: Unfortunately this requires custom expressions for each and every member, such as `$_.IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop` for the default gateway address and `$_.DNSServer.ServerAddresses -join " "` for the DNS servers. Isn't there a way to format the member the same way it would be in a table view? I tried `Out-String` and `.ToString()` and they all gave different (and useless) representations.

Comment: @BoppreH, if you want a table view, pipe to `Format-Table | Out-String` - please see my update. Generally, `Out-String` gives you the same representation as in the console as a multi-line string - or, with `-Stream` - as an array of lines. You can use it with or without a preceding explicit `Format-*` cmdlet call.

Comment: By "table/list view" I meant the way that individual *fields* are formatted in a table, not the table itself as a big string. I was basically looking for the same data that `Format-List` gave me, but in JSON. Anyway, you did most of the hard work in your ``ForEach-Object` example, so I'm accepting the answer. Thank you.