# Trying to run commands remote with powershell but not luck

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting

I'm looking for help to run commands on remote computers regarding a line with mcafee agent to get it command run remotely.

```
$Machines = Get-Content -Path "C:\server_list.txt"
foreach ($computer in $Machines){
  Write-host "Executing Events on $computer" -b "yellow" -foregroundcolor "red"
  $command = Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\cmdagent.exe" -ArgumentList "/e /l C:\temp"
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {$command}
}
```

When I executed this command run locally but not remotely.

I'm looking for help here I have not full experience but I'm started automating some task on my job.

Please suggest some tips

I really appreciate it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$command = Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\cmdagent.exe" -ArgumentList "/e /l C:\temp"`

This doesn't define a command *for later execution* with `Invoke-Command`, it *instantly executes* the `Start-Process` command, which is not your intent, and it is the reason it runs *locally*.

To fix that, you'd have to define it *as a script block* (`{ ... }`):
`$command = { Start-Proces ... }`, and then pass it *as-is* to `Invoke-Command`'s `-ScriptBlock` parameter (`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock $command`) (don't enclose it in `{ ... }` *again*).

Additionally, I suggest taking advantage of `Invoke-Command`'s ability to target *multiple* computers at once, in parallel, and to avoid using `Start-Process` for synchronous invocation of an external program in the same window.

To put it all together:

```
$machines = Get-Content -Path "C:\server_list.txt"

Write-host "Executing Events on the following computers: $machines" -b "yellow" -foregroundcolor "red"

# Define the command as a script block, which is a piece of PowerShell code
# you can execute on demand later.
# In it, execute cmdagent.exe *directly*, not via Start-Process.
$command = { & "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\cmdagent.exe" /e /l C:\temp }

# Invoke the script block on *all* computers in parallel, with a single
# Invoke-Command call.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machines -ScriptBlock $command
```

Note the need to use `&`, the call operator, to invoke the `cmdagent.exe` executable, because its path is *quoted* (of necessity, due to containing spaces).

---

Alternatively, you can define the script block directly in the `Invoke-Command` call:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machines -ScriptBlock {
  & "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\cmdagent.exe" /e /l C:\temp
}
```

A notable pitfall when targeting remote computers is that you cannot directly reference *local* variables in the (remotely executing) script block, and must instead explicitly refer to them via the `$using:` scope; e.g., `$using:someLocalVar` instead of `$someLocalVar` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35492616/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$command` is only valid for your local session - if you try to use it in a remote session, `$command` is `$null` and does nothing. Additionally, you are actually assigning `$command` whatever `Start-Process` returns, not what you want the command to be.

Just put the command in the script block (and while you're at it you can run this on every machine with a single command without having to loop over each one synchronously):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Machines -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\cmdagent.exe" -ArgumentList "/e /l C:\temp" }
```