# Powershell Get-WebsiteState using variable as Name input

Tags: powershell, scope, remoting

I'm writing a powershell script to get the status of some IIS sites and it works perfectly using a string as the name:

```
$service = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName  {Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-WebsiteState -Name "DefaultWebsite"}).value
```

However when I try to pass a variable in the name it no longer works and instead now returns the statuses of all IIS sites on my server

```
$service = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName  {Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-WebsiteState -Name "$serv"}).value
```

Nothing I seem to try resolves this issue - any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The accepted answer works, but in PSv3+ there is a simpler solution via the `$using:` scope - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35492616/45375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the $serv argument to the script block:

```
$service = (
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {
       param ($serv)
       Import-Module WebAdministration
       Get-WebsiteState -Name $serv
    } -ArgumentList $serv
).value
```

As mklement0 commented, you could also use the `using` scope in PS3+:

```
$service = (
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {
       Import-Module WebAdministration
       Get-WebsiteState -Name $using:serv
    }
).value
```