# Powershell Execute exe with command line arguments on remote computer

Tags: powershell, exe

I'm trying to run an exe on a remote computer using powershell without success.
when I run locally on the server like so it is running successfully

**"C:\Program Files\Syncovery\Syncovery.exe" /RUNX="myJobName" /S**

I've tried several ways running this remotely, but im getting all sorts of errors

```
$exe = "C:\Program Files\Syncovery\Syncovery.exe"
$arguments = '/RUNX="myJobName" /S'
$proc = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($exe, $arguments)
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

or

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverName -ScriptBlock {$proc.WaitForExit()}
```

*Error: Exception calling "Start" with "2" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified"
At line:3 char:1

- $proc = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($exe, $arguments)*

or

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverName -ScriptBlock {&$exe $arguments}
```

*Error: the expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.*

Comment: I believe you need to place all of the code in the scriptblock, not just the `$proc.WaitForExit()` line.

Comment: In short: Because the script block executes _remotely_, it knows nothing about the caller's _local_ variables. The simplest way to reference the caller's variable values is with the `$using:` scope - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35492616/45375).

Comment: sorry but couldn't figure out how to use '$using' in my case.

Comment: I dont have to use variables. I just placed the exe path in a variable for comfort reasons. the external exe is not recognized inside the scriptblock. 
`$syn = &$exe $arguments`  
    
`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s { $Using:syn  } -ArgumentList $arguments`